# About Queue Data Structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue, nodes, fifo

Hello Guys I know it is not the good way to write Queue but I want to understand this thing

here in my code I have a `Node` Class and there is just (`int data` and `Node Next`) inside it.

in other class, I am doing this

```
Node head = new Node(1);
            head.next = new Node(2);
            head.next.next = new Node(3);
           
            Node temp = head;
            temp.next.next.next = new Node(4);

 Console.WriteLine(head.data + "\n" + head.next.data + "\n" + head.next.next.data + "\n"+head.next.next.next.data);
```

I am getting this output.

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to understand why `head` printing found the last node which I create in Temp

can someone understand me and tell me why?

`Node Temp` just copied `head` and added a new Node which is 4
but what makes this last node appear in `head`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the reference types for this. So a class/object is a reference type .

A reference type ,extends System.Object and points to a location in the memory that contains the actual data.

So when you said Node temp=head`.

Now both of the object point to same location and any changes in one will change the other

https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type-with-examples

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3043992/a-deep-dive-value-and-reference-types-in-net.html

So first of all new keyword always creates new object.So as you can see temp and head are same when you assign head= temp

[image]

As soon as you say , `temp=temp.next`, now it will point to next node and now head and temp will not be same.Temp will point to the next node of head

[image]

Now as soon as you write `temp = new Node("10");`it creates new object and assign to temp.So new key word always creates new object

But if you do like this
temp.Data="10" without doing temp=new Node("10");, it will change both head and temp

[image];

Comment: That's clear I understand you.
but when there is a lot of (nexts) what I need to do is to make while loop like this

`while(temp.next!=null)
{
  temp=temp.next
}
temp.next=new Node......etc
`

in this way, while loop was destroying temp to arrive the last node
why head is not affected here.

Comment: your answer is clear

so I can change where the temp is pointing but when I change any data or creating a new Node both head and temp will be affected.
but now can I know how did you make this mouse hover information above `head` in the third image?
I am running an updated version of VS but hovering mouse over Head didn't give this slide.

Comment: while debugging you can do that, I am using Visual Studio 2019 and just hover over the object and then you can get all details of that object .

Comment: Please upvote if you find the answer useful.

Comment: I was just wondering
why when I do `temp.next=temp.next.next` the head get affected but when I do `temp=temp.next` the head will not get affected.
there is something not clear here.

Comment: In temp.next=temp.next.next, you are changing the next node value and changing it to one after. So as you change it , the head will change as it refers same object.In the case of tem= temp.next, you are not changing any node value, you are just assigning temp.next to temp

Comment: So if you do temp=temp.next and then change the data of temp like this temp.Data=1000, it will also change the head

Comment: So what you are developing is a linked list. So 1==>2==>3==>4. Now if you are in node 1 and you say temp.next=temp.next.next, it will change the temp next value to 3. So it will become 1==>3==>4. If you are just saying temp= temp.next, you are just referencing the next object which is 2 and assigning it to temp